# iPhone GMail Push Setup (Exchange) Delete > Bin rather than Delete > Archive?

Tags: iphone, email, gmail

I have GMail setup on my iPhone with push, as an exchange account. It's awesome. However, when I select to delete an email (as I often do - I get rather more rubbish than I'd like) it archives the email - and I want to delete it properly from my phone.

This is the opposite of a lot of questions, and I'm aware that if it's setup as a gmail account I can change this setting, but seemingly not if it's setup as an Exchange account.

Comment: are you using gMail's app or Apple's mail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enable the "Delete Email As Trash" setting through Google Sync. Google added this feature in 2012:

1. ***On your iOS device***, visit http://m.google.com/sync/settings and log in.
2. Select your device from the list on the "*Manage devices*" page.
3. Click the "*Enable "Delete Email As Trash" for this device*" checkbox.
4. Tap "*Save*" to accept the new setting.

[image]

Now when you delete an email on your iOS device, it will be sent to the "*Trash*" folder instead of the "*All Mail*" folder in Gmail.

*Note:* This feature is only relevant if you’ve setup your Gmail account in iOS mail as a Microsoft Exchange account.

Comment: You wonderful, wonderful person. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Any alternative solutions?

Comment: This solution worked for me, as of 05 August 2013 using iOS 6.x

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 6, go to Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > [your Gmail account] > and flip the "Archive Messages" switch to Off. Then, when you're viewing an email in your Gmail account, you'll notice that the archive button (box icon) in the toolbar has been replaced with a delete button (trash can icon).

Alternatively, if you tap and hold on the archive/delete button, a menu will pop up letting you choose archive or delete specifically, so you can control this on a per-message basis if you wish.